# Make IE 10 repeat svg background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I have an svg that I'm applying as the background to the body.  I'm using x-repeat, and it works in chrome and FF but in ie10 (actually ie11 beta) the background is squished and has giant bars in between each x-repeat

the link is here
http://knowledgecity.com/hrtools/workstyle/svgtest.php

The syle I'm using on the body is

```
<body style="margin:0em;background-image: url(background-opt.svg);background-size: 1339em 1000em;background-repeat:repeat-x;overflow:hidden">
```

What part of this style doesn't work in ie10? Or is it something else?

chrome:
[image: this is how it looks on chrome]

IE10:
[image: This is how it looks on ie10]

Comment: Thanks I added it but that did not change anything.

Comment: I'm thinking this could be an actual bug in ie, not just a "different way" of rendering.  you can see that the background is squished 50%. The reapeat is occuring at the right place, but the size is squished 50% in the x dimension

Comment: if you open the svg directly in ie10 it renders just fine http://knowledgecity.com/hrtools/workstyle/background-opt.svg This seems to have something to do with x-repeat in ie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, it turns out I needed to add

```
preserveAspectRatio="none slice"
```

to my svg element for ie to render it correctly.  That solved it.