# using SVG image as background in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I am having some problem using an SVG image as background in IE. It works for simple SVGs but not for others. I have an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/siddjain/c6sw8hxd/):

**HTML:**

```
<p>SVG image not repeating in IE</p>
<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div
{float: left;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
        border:1px solid black;
}   
#div1
{
    background:url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74728667/Interstate_75_icon.svg");
}
#div2
{
    background:url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74728667/Circle.svg");
}
#div3
{
    background:url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74728667/brick.svg");
}
```

**Result:**

**IE:**
[image]

**Chrome:**
[image]

**Is there something wrong in my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690457/make-ie-10-repeat-svg-background) question on the bricks.svg appears to fix the problem.

Comment: the problem is that using none for preserveAspectRatio causes the image to be scaled. i don't want the image to be scaled at all.

Comment: You might have to find the property that works for you...there's more than one. [**Preserve Aspect Ratio @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Comment: The interstate sign and the circle have a defined width and height. The bricks do not.  So the brick svg is scaling to fit. If you set a width and height in the svg it should then repeat as expected instead of scaling.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work on IE8 and below. You could either install plugins to make it work, or install plugins to work around it. ([SVGWeb](https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/), [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/))

Comment: This is an issue in IE11 too..so your "answer" should have been a comment

Comment: Your code is correct, but it is possible your SVG file isn't correctly rendered. Try http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor to optimize the SVG file and see if it solves the issue

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to add a comment"